# Does Media Foundation work on Windows 7?

Tags: ms-media-foundation, sharpdx

Even though this is a very simple question, I cannot seem find a definitive authoritative answer to it.

All the sample code I have found is meant to run on Windows 8, but I remember having read somewhere that Media Foundation was included in Vista.

Are some features only available on Windows 8? or can I safely develop for Media Foundation (via SharpDX) knowing that it will run on a Windows 7 machine?

Comment: Some features start with Win 7, some - with Win 8. Yes it does work.

Comment: @RomanR. So that would be a no then. Do you have a list of **which** functions (or functionality) are available on each OS release?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the MediaFoundation API is backward compatible with Windows Vista/7. Though there are a couple of API introduced for Windows 8 (for example [MediaEngine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh447918%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) that are not available in Windows 7. You can check if the API is accessible from Windows 7 at the botttom of each interface documentation on MediaFoundation msdn documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an authoritative comprehensive list of which functions/functionality are available starting on Windows 8, so I can be careful and not use that?

Comment: You can check the column `Platforms` from http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/n-sharpdx-mediafoundation and http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-mediafoundation-mediafactory, the list is not updated with recent changes in SharpDX but It should be roughly accurate.

Comment: I see. For some reason I was only looking at the "Applies to" part of the Description column.

Comment: A MediaFoundation sample for Win7 would be great to have. Something like a conversion of BasicPlayback http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb970475%28v=vs.85%29.aspx